# auto numbering for all the nodes and sub nodes of tree in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have numbering and sub-numbering to tree using a SQL query.

I have tried multiple ways, I am new to SQL.

```
WITH tree AS
(
    SELECT 
        c1.structureid, c1.parentid, c1.Text, 
        [level] = 1, 
        path = CAST(c1.structureid AS VARCHAR(100)),
        pathindex = 0, numericalMapping = '0.0'
    FROM 
        [ast].[Structure] c1
    WHERE 
        c1.parentid IS NULL 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        c2.structureid, c2.parentid, c2.Text, 
        [level] = tree.[level] + 1, 
        Path = CAST(tree.path + '/' + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(c2.structureid AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) AS VARCHAR(100)),
        pathindex = 0, numericalMapping =  '0.0'
    FROM 
        [ast].[Structure] c2 
    INNER JOIN 
        tree ON tree.structureid = c2.parentid
)
SELECT 
    tree.level, tree.path, tree.parentid, 
    REPLICATE('  ', tree.level - 1) + tree.Text AS description,
    C.* ,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tree.parentId ORDER BY tree.parentId) AS indx
FROM 
    tree 
INNER JOIN
    [ast].[Value] AS C ON tree.structureid = C.structureid 
ORDER BY 
    InstanceId, path
```

input Tables:
table 1
ValueId InstanceId  StructureId ChoiceId    Score
622 205 580 30  3
623 205 581 30  3
624 205 582 30  3
625 205 583 NULL    NULL
626 205 584 NULL    NULL
627 205 585 NULL    NULL
628 205 586 NULL    5
629 205 587 NULL    5
630 205 588 NULL    5
631 205 589 40  4
632 205 590 NULL    NULL
633 205 591 NULL    NULL

table 2
StructureId AssessmentId    ParentId    Required    Sequence    Text    Objective
580 127 NULL    1   0   Customer Satisfaction   NULL
581 127 580 1   1   Top Customers   NULL
582 127 580 1   1   Customer Feedback Process   NULL
583 127 NULL    1   0   Continuous Improvement  NULL
584 127 583 1   0   Gemba   NULL
585 127 583 1   0   Real-Time Status    NULL
586 127 583 -1  -1  TPM NULL
587 127 586 -1  0   Cleaning and Inspection NULL
588 127 586 1   1   Eliminate Contamination NULL
589 127 588 1   0   Test    NULL
590 127 NULL    0   0   SAP Mii NULL
591 127 590 0   0   Dispatch Reports    NULL

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb6xu.png)
table 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i51gX.png)
table 2

Note:
 I want to have one more column which will tell the index of each record.
example : 1,2,3
if there are children in 1 then 1.01, 1.02 and so on

Comment: Moreover, how can I have one more column which says the highest level in  grouped by InstanceId

Comment: I looks to me like you have that already. In the second or third column of your output? Hard to tell since the formatting has it scattered all over the place.

Comment: Sean, No... They are coming from the column value itself. please ignore those index.

Comment: Please post your input data and only necessary output fields.

Comment: data: [
        {id: 583, parentId: null, level:1 ,  description: " Continuous Improvement" },
         {id: 584, parentId: 583, level:2 ,  description: "  Gemba" },       
          {id: 585, parentId: 583, level:2 ,  description: "   Real-Time Status" },
        { id: 586, parentId: 583,  level:2  ,description: "   TPM" },
           { id: 587, parentId: 586, level:3 ,description: "    Cleaning and Inspection" },
         { id: 588, parentId: 586, level:3 , description: "    Eliminate Contamination" },       
          { id: 589, parentId: 588,level:4 , description: "      Test" }   ]

Comment: Please post data in the question. Comments are horrific for formatting. Might be worth checking out this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/